# How to get the container-instance-id of the local ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I run the following shell command to drain my ECS instance before rebooting it:

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ecs update-container-instances-state \
  --region eu-central-1 \
  --cluster mycluster \
  --status DRAINING \
  --container-instances $INSTANCE_ID
```

It gives me the following error:

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateContainerInstancesState operation: instanceId shorter than 36.

Apparently this is because it wants the ECS containerInstanceId which is different from the ec2InstanceId. What is the best way to find out the containerInstanceId of the local machine?

The way I figured out so far is

1. use `aws ecs list-container-instances` to get all the container instance IDs in the cluster
2. use `aws ecs describe-container-instances` to get the corresponding EC2 instance IDs
3. use instance metadata (`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`) to find out the local EC2 instance ID
4. Use `jq` combined with `grep` or some other tool to filter

This seems a little complicated. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I believe you should be inputting the container instance id and not the EC2 instance id. The container instance id looks like this: 1c3be8ed-df30-47b4-8f1e-6e68ebd01f34. I pulled that from the AWS API guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateContainerInstancesState.html

Comment: You're absolutely right. I solved it by using aws ecs list-container-instances, then aws ecs describe-container-instances along with some grepping and awking. Seems a little complicated for such a simple task though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a script on the instance, you can find the container instance ID from the ECS agent's [introspection API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-introspection.html).

If you're running a script from within an ECS task, you can use the [container metadata file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html).

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to populate a custom attribute on the instance containing the instance Id. For example, in your */etc/ecs/ecs.config*, you may have the following:

```
ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"ec2_instance\":\"i-0000000000000000000\"}
```

This can then be used in conjunction with the *--filter* parameter of *list-container-instances* to find the associated container instance.

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster <MY Cluster> --filter attribute:ec2_instance==i-0000000000000000000
```

If you are using the *cfn-init* script and CloudFormation, then this can be automated when you create the EC2 instance.

```
....
MyLaunchConfiguration:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
  Metadata:
    AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
      config: 
        commands: 
          00_configure_ecs_agent:
            command: |
              #!/bin/bash
                echo ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"ec2_instance\":\"$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)\"} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
...
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-container-instances.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html

Comment: Since this was posted, [Jose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6357583/jos%c3%a9-nobre-j%c3%banior) noticed that there is now a 'ec2InstanceId' attribute automatically populated and available for use with list-container-instances. No need fuss with custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed, this is fairly straight forward.

Using the [ECS Container Introspection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-introspection.html) endpoint, you get these values and pass them to the `aws ecs update-container-instances-state` command.

It can be useful to do this in [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) and add the results into `/etc/environment` so they are always readily available.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

CONTAINER_INSTANCE_ARN="$(curl -s --fail http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata | jq -er '.ContainerInstanceArn')"
CLUSTER="$(curl -s --fail http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata | jq -er '.Cluster')"

aws ecs update-container-instances-state --cluster "$CLUSTER" \
    --container-instances "$CONTAINER_INSTANCE_ARN" --status "DRAINING"
```

Adding them to `/etc/environment` via user data:

```sh
cat<<-EOF>>/etc/environment
CONTAINER_INSTANCE_ARN="$(curl -s --fail http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata | jq -er '.ContainerInstanceArn')"
CLUSTER="$(curl -s --fail http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata | jq -er '.Cluster')"
EOF
source /etc/environment
```

Notes:

- jq `-e` flag means to set the exit code if the key is not found.
- jq `-r` flag means to dump output as raw text instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

Here's ruby code I used for this:

```rb
require 'aws-sdk-ecs'

region = JSON.parse(`curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document`)['region']
instance_id = `ec2metadata --instance-id`.strip
cluster_name = `cat /etc/ecs/ecs.config | grep '^ECS_CLUSTER=' | cut -d "=" -f2`.strip

container_instance_arn = lambda do
  ECS_CLIENT.describe_container_instances({
    :cluster => cluster_name,
    :container_instances => ECS_CLIENT.list_container_instances({
      :cluster => cluster_name,
    }).container_instance_arns
  }).container_instances.select do |instance|
    instance.ec2_instance_id == instance_id
  end.first.container_instance_arn
end.call
```